# What is the structure of a vim .swp file?

Tags: python, vim

An application wants to shell text out to vim and know what edits are being made, in real time.

The .swp file provides this information. Can anyone provide guidance on how to read this binary file, say, with Python?

Comment: `open("yourfile.swp","rb")`?

Comment: note: I guess it would be easier to patch vim, than trying to parse the swap file...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I think OP is using "shell text out" as some sort of slang to mean "output text to console" (think "I shelled out $100 for these awesome tickets")

Comment: If you fail to find a doc describing Vim swap file structure you can try dig through the sources. `src/memline.c:ml_recover()` looks as a good start point

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

I did my own investigation into `.swp` file formats when I wrote my [ls.swp](https://github.com/adamhotep/misc-scripts/blob/master/ls.swp) tool that views `.swp` contents (that's a perl script with lots of documentation in it).

My key sources of interest were:

- A **Vim General** mailing list thread on [vim swap file format](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/vim-swap-file-format-td1193173.html)
- Official Vim documentation on [swap file recovery](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#swap-file)

Parsing this required a bit of reverse-engineering, and I was only able to extract certain data.  All I wanted to get out of it was some basic information about the status of the edited file.  My results look like this:

```
$ ls.swp .ls.swp.sw*
.ls.swp.swo:adamhotep@tabasco:~/git/misc-scripts/ls.swp (running) 85d ago
.ls.swp.swp:adamhotep@tabasco:~/git/misc-scripts/ls.swp 85d ago
```

I'm rather certain you're not going to get any real-time data since that'd just be a big pile of disk I/O for vim to maintain.

Comment: The swapfile is written whenever `updatecount` (default 200) characters are typed, or `updatetime` (default 4000) milliseconds pass without any input. So it's semi-realtime, and how realtime it is is adjustable.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on the swapfile contents to get real-time updates. Its format is geared towards Vim's uses, and its format isn't documented other than by its implementation. You would have to duplicate large parts of the algorithm, and maintain that whenever the internal format changes (without prior notice).

Alternatively, I would use one of the embedded languages (e.g. Python) to interface with the outside program that wants to get real-time updates. A Python function could periodically send along the entire buffer contents on a socket, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who replied.

I hoped .swp would be documented, maybe even code available to access it, seems not.

The suggestion to write a plugin in Python probably makes the most sense, I bet it's possible to hook to something like 'on_keystroke' and maintain a mirror I can understand.

'shell out' as in 'write this chunk of text to a temp file, open that file in vim, when vim exits, write the temp file contents to a replacement chunk of text'

PS: $100 is way too much to shell out for those tickets